# Do not rotate scale title at xAxis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So I am using chart.js and my xAxis title rotates I would like to set this to false or something that my xAxis title won't rotate at all

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your options.scales:

```
xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        maxRotation: 0 // angle in degrees
    }
}]
```

Example of options:

```
options: {
    responsive: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                maxRotation: 0 // angle in degrees
            }
        }]
    }
}
```